# Why does require choose the latest version of a gem?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, rubygems, bundler

If I load a gem, let's say `activerecord`, in IRB `require` chooses the latest version of `activerecord`. Programmatically, what is influencing this decision to choose the latest gem version? Is `require` doing this, or is there something in the loaded IRB that forces requires to choose the latest version?

Here are my activerecord gems installed by bundler:

```
➜  ~ ls -al /Users/robskrob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activere
activerecord-4.2.10/   activerecord-5.0.0.1/  activerecord-5.1.2/    activerecord-5.1.3/    activerecord-5.1.4/    activerecord-5.1.5/    activerecord-5.1.6/    activeresource-5.0.0/
```

And here is an example IRB session:

```
➜  ~ irb
2.4.1 :001 > require 'active_record'
 => true
2.4.1 :002 > Gem.loaded_specs['activerecord'].version
 => #<Gem::Version "5.1.6">
2.4.1 :003 >
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I load a gem, let's say `activerecord`, in IRB `require` chooses the latest version of `activerecord`.

Actually, it chooses the latest version [*that doesn't conflict with any already activated gem*](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/master/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb#L107-L109).

> Programmatically, what is influencing this decision to choose the latest gem version? Is `require` doing this, or is there something in the loaded IRB that forces requires to choose the latest version?

This is `require`s job. More specifically, it is the job of [the monkey-patched `require` from the RubyGems library](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/master/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb#L25-L138), not [the original `require` from the Ruby core library](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-require).

This is just simple separation of concerns: IRb is a REPL, not a package management system, it *shouldn't* know anything about packages.

Comment: than you very much for your answer. Pardon my ignorance -- and perhaps this should be an SO post on its own -- but why does an IRB session use the `require` from the monkey patched version in RubyGems and does not use the `require` from the Ruby core library?

Comment: This has nothing to do with IRb. Versions of Ruby after 1.9 automatically load the RubyGems library at startup, unless explicitly disabled by passing `--disable-rubygems`. RubyGems monkeypatches `Kernel#require` to look for files in gems in addition to the `$LOAD_PATH`. Very old versions of RubyGems didn't do that, you had to "activate" a gem first (which adds it to the `$LOAD_PATH`) by calling `Kernel#gem`. The monkeypatched version of `require` will search for the file in all installed gems and activate a gem for you if it finds it.